# css odd even not working with pseudo-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container div names `wrapper` and it has several child divs named `thumb`
I want to apply css `pseudo elements` with the even and odd.

### My codes are

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="col-half">
      <div class="thumb">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-half">
      <div class="thumb">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-half">
      <div class="thumb">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-half">
      <div class="thumb">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### And my css:

```
.wrapper:nth-child(even) .thumb:after{
    //some codes
}
.wrapper:nth-child(odd) .thumb:after{
    //some codes
}
```

But i am getting only `odd` styles.

Comment: what is your expected output.. create a demo?

Comment: Find an **explanation** about what you got wrong in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `odd` and even relationship is applied based on sibling index, you need to apply it on `col-half` as that is the repeated element.

Since your `thumb` element is the first child of its parent, it will only satisfy the `odd` selector

```css
.wrapper .col-half:nth-child(even) .thumb:after {
  content: 'x'
}

.wrapper .col-half:nth-child(odd) .thumb:after {
  content: 'y'
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-half">
    <div class="thumb">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-half">
    <div class="thumb">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-half">
    <div class="thumb">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-half">
    <div class="thumb">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding about :nth-child as it does **not** work as "nth child of this container" but as "am I the nth child of my parent?".

So you need to apply `:nth-child(odd/even)` to `.col-half`:

```
.col-half:nth-child(even) .thumb:after{
    //some codes
}
.col-half:nth-child(odd) .thumb:after{
    //some codes
}
```

The name for this selector has really caused many misunderstandings as it is too easy to misunderstand the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-half:nth-child(even) {
    color: green;
}
.col-half:nth-child(odd) {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uxkLc3kv/1/)**

In your css, You are using the parent div for showing even and odd. Instead you need to use odd / even for child elements which repeats

```
.col-half:nth-child(even) .thumb{
  background:#ccc;
}
.col-half:nth-child(odd) .thumb{
   background:#f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This One**

```
.wrapper .col-half:nth-child(2n) .thumb:after {
  content: '';
}

.wrapper .col-half:nth-child(2n-1) .thumb:after {
  content: '';
}
```